# RRDtool setup for 5 minutes intervals but with data delivered every 30 minutes?

Tags: rrdtool

Can I setup the RRDtool so that the data values have intervals of 5 minutes but the data is delivered to RRDtool every 30 minutes? I need the chart to be clocked with 5 minutes interval as well (X axis) but refreshed every 30 minutes.

Use case: I have a DIY weather station that communicates with the world with GPRS. It collects the weather data every 5 minutes and stores it until 6 sessions like this are done and then sends the bulk of 6 measurement information via GPRS. 
Sending the data every 5 minutes is inefficient in terms of power usage and the data transfer tolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you feed data into RRDtool, you can just tell it the relevant time instead of the default of "NOW" rounded to the next interval. This way, you can feed data points into it at will. See the [relevant documentation](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdupdate.en.html).

Comment: Thank you SvW, it seems I missed this `--timestamp` parameter and which apparently is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can.  You may want to use an area plot on the chart so you won't have gaps.